# What does "paired" Certificate & Key look like in a keystore?

Tags: ssl

I got a pkcs12 file and a crt file which I have imported into a keystore. But I am not sure the keystore "knows" they are paired. (I am only assuming it actually needs to know.)

keystore -list:

```
Keystore type: BKS
Keystore provider: BC
Your keystore contains 2 entries
my_cert, , trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ...
my_key, , PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ...
```

UPDATE: Only now I have noticed they have the same value in "Certificate fingerprint". I suppose that's the trick...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the trick. The trustedCertEntry is superfluous. A PrivateKeyEntry always contains the certificate (chain) as well.

The PKCS#12 file obviously contained not only the key but also the certificate (otherwise the import would have failed).

You can view certificate details (especially the certificate chain that is associated with a key pair entry) with the *verbose* switch "**-v**". For example this PrivateKeyEntry has 2 certificates associated:

```
keytool.exe -v -list -keystore ...

Alias name: cert
Creation date: Jan 24, 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=cert
Issuer: CN=root
Serial number: 5576e50e
Valid from: Tue Jun 09 15:07:33 CEST 2015 until: Thu Jun 09 15:07:33 CEST 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
        ...
Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=root
Issuer: CN=root
Serial number: 5576e4f3
Valid from: Tue Jun 09 15:07:06 CEST 2015 until: Thu Jun 09 15:07:06 CEST 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
         ...
```